# How to display on a final map the scale of a vector field marker?

Tags: qgis, vector, mapping, scale, markers

I'm using the vector field marker to display earth deformation. For that, I defined the vector field marker with cartesian components (**x (field_3)** as displacement in West-East and **y (field_4)** as displacement North-South). Just for viewing, I defined a scale of 500 mm. I want to produce the map of the field with its respective legend. How to include/display the value of the scaled symbol (arrow) in the legend? (arrow scaling factor or the representation in length units -cm, mm- of the scaled arrow)

[image]